# sequelize aggregate function gives wrong result

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I'm newbie and sequelize aggregate function makes me confused because it gave me different result than expected. I'm trying to get a total price with `sequelize.fn('sum', ...)`, and somehow sequelize only gives me the the total of first data of the associated model instead of summing all the result. My code as follows:

```js
Training.findAll({  
  where: {
    owner_id: payload
  },
  attributes: ['id', [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('training_classes.price')), 'totalPrice']],
  include: [{
    model: TrainingClass,
    as: 'training_classes',
    attributes: ['id', 'price'],
  }],
  group: ['Training.id', 'training_classes.id']
})
```

And the result of the query :

```js
[
    {
      "id": "45",
      "totalPrice": "300000",
      "training_classes": [
        {
          "id": "94",
          "price": "300000"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "totalPrice": "1000000",
      "training_classes": [
        {
          "id": "14",
          "price": "1000000"
        },
        {
          "id": "15",
          "price": "300000"
        },
        {
          "id": "16",
          "price": "200000"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "47",
      "totalPrice": "100000",
      "training_classes": [
        {
          "id": "97",
          "price": "100000"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "39",
      "totalPrice": "1000000",
      "training_classes": [
        {
          "id": "81",
          "price": "1000000"
        },
        {
          "id": "82",
          "price": "300000"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "24",
      "totalPrice": "300000",
      "training_classes": [
        {
          "id": "46",
          "price": "300000"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "totalPrice": "200000",
      "training_classes": [
        {
          "id": "11",
          "price": "200000"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "49",
      "totalPrice": "100000",
      "training_classes": [
        {
          "id": "100",
          "price": "100000"
        },
        {
          "id": "99",
          "price": "1000000"
        },
        {
          "id": "101",
          "price": "100000"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "20",
      "totalPrice": "200000",
      "training_classes": [
        {
          "id": "38",
          "price": "200000"
        },
        {
          "id": "35",
          "price": "400000"
        },
        {
          "id": "37",
          "price": "500000"
        },
        {
          "id": "36",
          "price": "100000"
        }
      ]
    },
]
```

as you can see, the totalPrice only from the first element of training_classes, not the entire data of it. How can I resolve this? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum all records in `TrainingClass` that have the same `Training.id` then you need to indicate no attributes for `TrainingClass` and indicate only `Training.id` in `group` option:

```js
Training.findAll({  
  where: {
    owner_id: payload
  },
  attributes: ['id', [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('training_classes.price')), 'totalPrice']],
  include: [{
    model: TrainingClass,
    as: 'training_classes',
    attributes: [],
  }],
  group: ['Training.id']
})
```

If you group by `TrainingClass.id` then you'll get grouped results for each record that has unique `TrainingClass.id` value and literally every record of `TrainingClass` has unique `id` value.

Comment: nice, it works now. But it led me to another concern. Say I want to associate TrainingClass with TrainingClassStudent, and I want to track the income of owner_id per month by summing TrainingClass price based on student created_at. If I want to use sum, then I need to add attributes in TrainingClass, and then the postgres will yell at me to add training_classes.id in group, which will ruin the totalPrice result (?). How do I solve it?

Comment: For more complex aggregating queries I recommend to use plain SQL queiries and execute them by `Sequelize.query`